# how can I go back to an error with bundle install that no start the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, gemfile

to load my rails 3.2.8 app on Heroku, I put in Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and I gave 'bundle install', forgetting to give '-- without production' and now when I give 'rails s', the console gives me error: Could not find railties '..my gems..' (gem: load error) and Heroku gives me error when I give: heroku run rake db:migrate..In Gemfile I just put the gem 'sqlite3' and gave 'bundle install' but same error. How can I go back with bundle?

Comment: Could you run `bundle install` again and test it ?

Comment: in Gemfile I just put the gem 'sqlite3' and gave 'bundle install' but same error :(

Comment: excuse, almost the same error, it gives me: could not find bundler, not railties

Comment: try delete Gemfile.lock and run again `bundle install --without production`.

Comment: same error, it give me error in c:/program/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it looks like you do not have bundler installed or at least accessible in this environment.

Are you using rvm ? If so are you in the right gemset with the right ruby version ?

You will have to fix your local environment before make it working on Heroku in order to have a proper `Gemfile.lock`, also when it will work on local, it should work fine on heroku.

If you do not use rvm / rbenv, maybe you can start by installing bundler properly : `gem install bundler`

Comment: I figured out what was the problem, Heroku toolbelt install ruby192 when I have ruby 193, then the bundler fails.  Now how do I load my application on Heroku with ruby ​​193?

Comment: You probably want to use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/) to handle multiple versions of ruby in your windows machine.

Comment: I installed pik and I put ruby 187 and 193. then I installed Heroku, which automatically installs ruby 192 in c: \ Program Files (x86) \ ruby​​-1.9.3 \ bin but I can not add it to pik ...

Comment: I try to do 'pik add C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ruby​​-1.9.3 \ bin' but the console gives me error: 'could not find a ruby version at c: \ Program' probably wrong with the command spaces, I can not find a solution

Comment: I would suggest you to open another issue explaining your specific pik setup / problems.